# Where do you put input file in eclipse(java) in order to read it from console command?

Tags: java, eclipse, console, resources, workspace

I am writing a java program in eclipse(galileo version).  The program reads simple user data from input file specified at console command and process it.

But I am not sure where I should place this input file inside eclipse workspace, so that when I run program in eclipse and type in input file name, it can be found and program can process it.

and is there way to set file path so that I can just place input file anywhere and specified the file path at runtime?

thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Java process is started with the project directory as the working directory by default.

Answer (score 6):

The default working directory, when you run a Java app in Eclipse, is the project directory. If you place your data file in that directory, you can simply refer to the file without any preceding path. You can also change the working directory but modifying the launch properties for your app.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can just specify the file path as an argument to your Java process.  Under the Run menu, choose Run Configurations...   You should see your class under Java Applications.  Select the Arguments tab and just specify the path in the Program Arguments field.