# Where to put a .txt file in java that it can be read using eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Java isn't able to read the file konto.txt that i put in the src folder next to all .java files. where do I have to put the file in order that it can be read? or do I have to change the main method? I did it first in bluej and it worked perfectely with the existing source code.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {

    String filename = "konto.txt";
    ArrayList kontoliste = null;
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    try{
        fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
        in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        kontoliste = (ArrayList) in.readObject();
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }  

    Kontoverwaltung kontover = new Kontoverwaltung(kontoliste); 
    kontover.starten();//Starte Kontoverwaltung.
```

thank you.

Comment: This may help, try creating a .txt file with Java, and see where it puts it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929415/where-do-you-put-input-file-in-eclipsejava-in-order-to-read-it-from-console-co

Comment: It's different enough, imo. The OP may not run it via cmd.

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse reads the file from the working directory of the launched program. By default, Eclipse sets the working copy to the path of the project's root directory (typically the directory that contains the `src` directory).

You can change the working directory from the **Run Configurations** dialog under the **Arguments** section.

Comment: yes this is right so if you are using project `foo` the file can be read if you put it in the `foo` folder where the `src` and `bin` folder also reside.

Answer (score 0):

You can write down the full-path of konto.txt file,for example ,something like this "c:\test
\konto.txt"