# How to read a text file for java pig latin?

Tags: java

I am updating my code for pig latin to read a text file that reads:

```
This is a test   
Here is a second line
 and a third
```

My code is outputting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: data.txt (The system cannot find the file 
specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at PigLatin2.main(PigLatin2.java:15)
```

My code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class PigLatin2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));

        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("\"" + line + "\"" + " in pig latin is \"");
            Scanner words = new Scanner(line);
            while (words.hasNext()) {
                String word = words.next();
                String pigLatin = pigLatinWord(word);
                System.out.print(pigLatin + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("\"");
        }
    }

    // Convert one word to pig Latin.
    // Precondition: s is not an empty string
    // Postcondition: returns a new string that is the pig Latin
    // form of s
    public static String pigLatinWord(String s) {
        String pigWord;
        if (isVowel(s.charAt(0))) {
            pigWord = s + "-way";
        } else if (s.startsWith("th") || s.startsWith("Th")) {      // or 
(s.toUpperCase().startsWith("TH"))
            pigWord = s.substring(2) + "-" + s.substring(0,2) + "ay";
        } else {
            pigWord = s.substring(1,s.length()) + "-" + s.charAt(0) + "ay";
        }
        return pigWord;
    }

    //---------------------------------------------
    // Determines whether c is a vowel character
    // Precondition: c contains a letter
    // Postcondition: returns true when c is a vowel
    public static boolean isVowel(char c) {
        String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
        return (vowels.indexOf(c) >= 0);    // when index of c in vowels is not -1, c is a vowel
    }
}
```

How can I fix this to read the file correctly? Is there something wrong with another part of the code?

Comment: It's not finding your file. Where is the file?

Comment: I added it into the java class and its located on my desktop

Comment: Since you did not include a path in your file, it should be in the directory that you started java from.

Comment: I am a little confused to what that means

Comment: How do you run your program?

Comment: i use eclipse to run my program

Comment: Add the data file to the root level of the project. I think that might work.

Comment: I tried that and if i did it correctly it did not work

Comment: According to this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929415/where-do-you-put-input-file-in-eclipsejava-in-order-to-read-it-from-console-co, the project folder is the one it should be in.